# Scoring relevancy in Azure Search

Tags: azure, search

Is it possible to apply a profile scoring considering that a file must have a greater relevancy for one country than others?

How can I manage a scoring like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add [Scoring Profiles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/Add-scoring-profiles-to-a-search-index) to Azure Search index

The example in documentation gives sample for boosting score based on geo location.